# What would be an intuitive icon for expectations?

Tags: gui-design, icons

Orders in my application can have expectations of the customer associated with the order. For example a customer may expect a certain dresscode, he'd expect a follow-up call and so on. The seller will notice these 'expectations' and put them in with the order.

I Googled expectation, but I doubt icons of expecting women is intuiative for this case. Anyone?

Comment: Very hard. An expectation is a very abstract thing, therefor it's hard to think of an icon for this. I doubt if "expectation" is also the correct term. Maybe something like "special requirement" or "special wishes" suits better? But for those terms it's equially hard to find an icon that describes the idea. Why exactly is it necessary to find an icon for it?

Comment: My users prefer pictures to recognize data quickly. And you are probably right on the term, it might not be correct...

Comment: @ rozon: Sure, but the problem here is that there is probably no good picture for users to quickly recognize it. In that case it is advisable to use text instead.

Comment: @BaGi: I _do_ understand that there isn't a universal solution to this. Use the example I accepted below. Red for techs, green for invoice, yellow for sales rep. It could be solved by just the color, but the graphic representation adds a litle extra to it. IMHO anyway...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is to combine the *thing* that is expected, with a thought bubble:

Generic expectation: [image]

Expectation of phone call:  [image]

But the problem is, will your users *get it* in your context? Really question as to whether icons - especially individual icons for each thing are needed before going down this route.

Also consider: is *expectation* really the right word for what you need. It's highly unusual. Is *requirements*, *additional items*, *extras*, or some other terminology more commonly used during e-commerce checkout procedures perhaps more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

I highly doubt that you will find something like this.  You could go with an icon for a suit if it is specifically dress code, but if it is general you are better off using text.  Clarity wins (or at least should)